# Data replication in hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

I am a beginner learning Hadoop. Is it possible that 2 different data blocks from the same file could be stored in the same data node? For example: blk-A and blk-B from file "file.txt" could be placed in the same data node (datanode 1).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#Replica+Placement%3A+The+First+Baby+Steps) is the documentation that explains block placement policy. Currently, HDFS replication is 3 by default which means there are 3 replicas of a block. The way they are placed is:

1. One block is placed on a datanode on a unique rack.
2. Second block is placed on a datanode on a different rack.
3. Third block is placed on a different datanode on the same rack as
   second block.

This policy helps when there is an event such as datanode is dead, block gets corrupted, etc.

> Is it possible?

Unless you make changes in the source code, there is no property that you can change that will allow you to place two blocks on same datanode.

My opinion is that placing two blocks on same datanode beats the purpose of HDFS. Blocks are replicated so HDFS can recover for reasons described above. If blocks are placed on same datanode and that datanode is dead, you will lose two blocks instead of one.

Comment: Hi Sam, Your answers helps me a lot. But I have something more to know. What If a file has 5 different blocks. Among these 5 blocks , 2 of its  blocks could it be placed in a same datanode (Datanode1= Blk A, Blk B)? If so then when  datanode1 fails then 2 blocks (A,B) of a same file will be crashed, is it will be OK?

Comment: @DebbrotoSarkerDebu my answer focused on replicated blocks. If a file has five blocks how they are placed is based on HDFS algorithm which is most likely randomly. I believe the first block is placed on a rack close to the client whereas other two are placed on rack away from the client so as to reduce network bandwidth when accessing the data block.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the cluster topology. Hadoop tries to distribute data among data centers and data nodes. But What if you only have one data center ? or if you have only one node cluster (pseudo cluster). In those cases the optimal distribution doesn't happen and it is possible that all blocks end in the same data node. In production it is recommended have more than one data center (physically, not only in configuration) and at least the same number of data nodes than the replication number.

Comment: Hi, Rojo. I have another thing to know. Recently I read a paper of covering subset and non covering subset for energy efficiency in hadoop cluster. My question is that in hadoop cluster is the covering subset nodes always remains turned on even there is no request from client for the data that is in those covering subset.

Comment: Please create a new question for a new topic.